# Steps to port an SWF to an Android live wall paper

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, live-wallpaper

I have a simple SWF video loop I made a couple years ago that looks nice enough I'd like to make it into a live wall paper for my android device.

Is it possible to do this without rewriting too much?

I have my Android SDK set up, and found some information spread out on items such as...

1. Android Tutorial: [CubeLiveWallpaper](https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html)
2. [Create Android Live Wallpaper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108390/How-To-Create-Android-Live-Wallpaper) and
3. [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657963/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-flex-component-in-a-pure-java-android-application)

I understand having swf in android implies I'll need adobe air, and that this may slow the application down.  So,

1. Is this possible?
2. Anything else I should know, tutorial-style, for porting SWF to Android live wall paper?
3. Are there better ways to do this that still involve minimal modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably not going to be able to embed the SWF directly into the wallpaper.  It looks like live wall paper uses specific drawing APIs... That being said what you may be able to do is export the swf (if it is more of a movie than interactive) to a .mov... Once it is an .mov file you can easily make it any video format you want.  You would probably have better luck embedding those into the live wallpaper rather than the swf.
So you could use this:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=804720
Which let's you set the live wallpaper to any video with lots of codecs supported.