# Android live wallpaper from swf file

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I want to create a live wallpaper on android, I already paint an animation and now I have .swf or .gif file, I read some articles and tutorials, but they are not useful in my case. So is it possible to create such wallpaper and what engine would be better for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try AndEngine .You can export all of your swf/flash assets and create your LiveWallpaper. Also, see this link : [Steps to port an SWF to an Android live wall paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962849/steps-to-port-an-swf-to-an-android-live-wall-paper)